# Error in dpkg-configure: Can not find file "symbols/u" in any known directory

Tags: package-management, dpkg

After upgrading to vivid, I keep getting this error for each `apt-get` operation or when running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` directly:

```
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu5) ...
Error loading new keyboard description
/usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/u" in any known directory
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

That is followed by a number of dependency problems like this:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu5); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kbd:
 kbd depends on console-setup | console-setup-mini; however:
  Package console-setup is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-mini is not installed.
```

All in all, that leaves the following packages unconfigured:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
 ubuntu-minimal
 xserver-xorg-core
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev
 xserver-xorg-input-mouse
 xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom
 xserver-xorg-input-all
 xserver-xorg
 xorg
 ubuntu-desktop
 xserver-xorg-video-r128
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
 xserver-xorg-video-ati
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
 xserver-xorg-video-intel
 xserver-xorg-video-mga
 xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
 xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
 xserver-xorg-video-savage
 xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
 xserver-xorg-video-trident
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware
 xserver-xorg-video-all
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not aware that I made any manual changes to the files involved or installed alternative versions of any of these. Then again, the base system I started with (a 14.04 LTS) came pre-installed with the laptop and may have contained vendor modifications from Tuxedo.

Any hints what may have caused these failures? Googling the `ckbcomp` error message was not enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, should solve your problem:

sudo apt-get remove keyboard-configuration
sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: That also removes the other packages mentioned above, what about those?

Comment: I finally tried this and had to repair my system to get it to boot again. :-( Then again, the whole cycle did solve the problem. But I kind of hesitate to accept an answer that breaks the system to the point that I need to boot into rescue mode.

Comment: I've done the same on two servers with the same problem and solved smoothly.  I've done the same on two servers with the same problem and solved it.  I do the commands I said earlier, and is 5 stars. Restart and test, all OK

Comment: I could imagine you're not starting X11 on your servers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I found two approaches to fix this.

Try first:

Open the file `/etc/default/keyboard` with your favorite editor and change the value of `XKBLAYOUT` to `"us"`.

If this did not help try this:

```
sudo -i
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
ln -s us u
```